# Pasing request params to Mongo from Node Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Sorry for very newbie question. I have setup Node, Express, and MongoDB. I have created a basic routing rule and am attempting to pass a parameter as such:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/req_summary/:approved', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('req_summary').find({approved:req.params.approved}).toArray(function (err, items) {
        res.json(items);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

My document in Mongo contains a field:

```
approved:0
```

The request coming from my router is treating the value as a string and as such is looking for:

```
approved:"0"
```

How do I pass the parameter from my router req object to Mongo as a number and not a string?

Answer (score 0):

All parameters your received from your HTTP request are string, so you have to parse it into the proper data type/JSON object.

In your case you have to use the parseInt method or create a Number:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/req_summary/:approved', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;

    var approved_value = parseInt(req.params.approved);

     // or
     // var approved_value = Number(req.params.approved);

    db.collection('req_summary').find({"approved":approved_value}).toArray(function (err, items) {
        res.json(items);
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

You can look at this documentation page : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Since it is a very common question in the context of MongoDB, you also have to create an ObjectId, Long or any other BSON object. You can import that from the bson module. ( see https://www.npmjs.org/package/bson )